# Python, Opencv, Imutils: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.7, imutils

I am trying to feed live video to the Tkinter window. I am using imutils.video for the Videostream. When I tried to run the code I am getting below-mentioned error. 
runfile('C:/Users/Ravi/Face_Detector/opencv_tkinter.py', wdir='C:/Users/Ravi/Face_Detector')

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Ravi\opencv_tkinter.py", line 37, in <module>
show_frame() #Displayq

  File "C:\Users\Ravi\opencv_tkinter.py", line 23, in show_frame
_, frame = cap.read()

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

When I am using cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0), then everything works fine. What can be the difference between 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) and cap = VideoStream(src=0).start()? In my other applications I am using cap = VideoStream(src=0).start(), that is why I need to stick with this. Can not afford to use cv2.VideoCapture. Any help is appriciated!

code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import time

#Set up GUI
window = tk.Tk()  #Makes main window
window.title("Test_1")
window.config(background="#FFFFFF")

#Graphics window
imageFrame = tk.Frame(window, width=600, height=600)
imageFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=2, pady=2)

#Capture video frames

cap = VideoStream(src=0).start()
time.sleep(2.0)

def show_frame():
    _, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    frame = Image.fromarray(frame)
    frame = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=frame)
    display.img = frame #Shows frame for display 1
    display.configure(image=frame)
    window.after(10, show_frame) 

myLable1 = tk.Label(imageFrame, text = "Title_1", bg='blue', fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 16))
myLable1.grid(row= 1, column= 0)
display = tk.Label(imageFrame)
display.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)  #Display 1

show_frame() #Displayq
window.mainloop()  #Starts GUI
```

Comment: Does making `cap` global help?

Comment: @paradoxlover with global cap, it does not work. I have tried with frame = cap.read() and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried with frame = cap.read() and it worked